# What is a “checkout solution”?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard this phrase: *checkout solution*. What does that mean exactly? Here is [an example](https://www.bongous.com/global-ecommerce/checkout/).

> Bongo Checkout is an integrated and secure international checkout solution that enables your business to reach international consumers through your existing eCommerce infrastructure. Checkout enhances transactions and offers a wealth of benefits.

Does it mean a solution for paying?

Comment: Yes, it means a solution for paying.

Comment: "Checkout" is what you do at the "checkout counter" where the cash register is in a standard brick-and-mortar store.  The term has been appropriated by eCommerce to refer (in varying degrees) to the processes involved in recording an order, handling payment, and initiating shipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In business jargon, the word *solution* is commonly (indeed, incessantly) used as a fancy way to refer to a commercial product, service, or method. Thus, a proprietary method for solving problems posed by dissolved chemicals might be termed a "solution solution solution."

*Checkout*, meanwhile, refers to the last stage of the retail buying process, which online entails identifying a payment method and source, transferring the appropriate funds, specifying the quantity and identity of the products purchased, and designating a destination address where the products should be delivered.

Put the two words together, and you get "checkout solution," or  "a commercial product, service, or method for handling the last stage of the retail buying process."